# How to solve hashmap to string problem in android

Tags: android

I'm Trying to read data from Firebase but app crashes on generate error in logcat below. I have tried all solutions available on stackoverflow and other sites but still i m failed to solve this issue I have made changes and shared necessary code here

.gradle Project (dependencies)

```
    dependencies {
                 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
                 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
                 }
```

app.gradle (dependencies)

```
    dependencies {
                 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
                 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
                 implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
                 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
                 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
                implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
                testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
                androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
                androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
                implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   }
```

main.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
        initViews();
        mBtn.setOnClickListener(this::readData);
    }

    public void readData(View view) {
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                setT.setText(data);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                setT.setText("Sorry Data");
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mBtn = findViewById(R.id.mBtn);
        setT = findViewById(R.id.setT);
    }
}
```

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNvvG.png)

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Post the error log

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your code, @Abdul Qadeer can you post the MainActivity code

Comment: Please add your database structure and initialization of the mRef variable

Answer (score 0):

try replace your database implementation version 17.0.0 to this version

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```

and it will work

Comment: you have not initialize (myRef) in your code !! you need to create object from (Firebasedatabase) and initialize it in (onCreate) method first

Comment: initialized with getReference() method